# Systemd stops Mysql service and does not restart it

Tags: systemd, mysql, services

I've got a server (Ubuntu 18.04) running at my school to provide access to an LMS (Moodle). It's running basically three services:

1. nginx
2. php-fpm
3. mysql

Nothing fancy. However, today I was called because the site reported that it can't access the database. SSH'ed in, checked the mysql service and, yeah, it was stopped. But no errors. Restarted the service and it runs fine, again, no errors.
Checked the logs, `/var/log/mysql/error.log` is empty. So are almost all the others, not shedding any light, save for something in the syslog:

```
May  5 06:56:01 moodle CRON[18512]: (www-data) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php >/dev/null)
May  5 06:56:16 moodle systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
May  5 06:56:35 moodle systemd[1]: Reloading.
May  5 06:56:35 moodle systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
May  5 06:56:35 moodle systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
[...]
May  5 06:56:37 moodle mysqld[2078]: 2020-05-05T06:56:37.143770Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
May  5 06:56:37 moodle systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
May  5 06:56:37 moodle systemd[1]: Reloading.
May  5 06:56:42 moodle systemd[1]: message repeated 3 times: [ Reloading.]
May  5 06:56:46 moodle systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
```

However, I cannot figure out where this systemd command to shutdown the mysql server comes from in the first place. I do not want that - after all, it's leaving the nginx and php-fpm services alone.

Googling the issue only leads me to stuff that's not related to what I'm seeing.

Comment: From the log this seems to be related to unattended OS updates through APT. Can you check `/var/log/dpkg.log` and `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see which packages were being updated when the issue occured?

Comment: ```2020-05-05 06:56:32 upgrade mysql-server:all 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2020-05-05 06:56:32 status half-configured mysql-server:all 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2020-05-05 06:56:32 status unpacked mysql-server:all 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2020-05-05 06:56:32 status half-installed mysql-server:all 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2020-05-05 06:56:32 status half-installed mysql-server:all 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2020-05-05 06:56:32 status unpacked mysql-server:all 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
```